# Pipeline preprocessing step turns model score values to NaN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to evaluate scores for a series of models and have put together a pipeline for processing the data and fitting the models. My code is:

```
    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('encoder', LabelEncoder()),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
    

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, selector(dtype_include="number")),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_exclude="number"))
    ])


    scoring = {'acc': 'accuracy',
               'log_loss': 'neg_log_loss',
              'recall': 'recall',
              'auc':'roc_auc',
              'f1':'f1'}
    
     # define models
    models, names, accuracy, log_loss, recall, roc, f1 = list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list()
   
    # LR
    models.append(LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'))
    names.append('LR')

    #Lasso
    models.append(LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear',penalty='l1'))
    names.append('LA')


    #RF
    models.append(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
    names.append('RF')

for i in range(len(models)):
    # evaluate the model and store results
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None)
    pipeline = Pipeline([ ('prep', preprocessor),('model', model)])
    scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, scoring=scoring,
                             cv=cv, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
    accuracy=list(scores["test_acc"])
    log_loss=list(scores['test_log_loss'])
    recall=list(scores['test_recall'])
    auc=list(scores['test_auc'])
    f1=list(scores['test_f1'])
    # summarize and store
    print('{} accuracy:{} logloss:{}, recall:{}, auc:{}, f1:{}'.format(names[i], mean(accuracy), mean(log_loss), mean(recall), mean(auc), mean(f1)))
```

The code works fine when I remove the preprocess step from the pipeline but when I include it, all the scores that print in the end are "nan" (even though the models are being fit because it is saving the fit time). Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is this scikit-learn? Not everyone will know, so would be nice if you can show the import statements.  You could also tag it with the package name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've added the tag.